# Determining coordinates of text label in a d3 axis

Tags: svg, d3.js

I'm having difficulty determining the starting coordinate of the bounding box for the svg text element that corresponds to the label for a D3.js ordinal x-axis.

From the current code the text label DOM node x attributes have values of 0.  However the label text is translated.  Thus I would use svg.selectAll("g.x.axis g.tick.major").attr("transform") to determine the transform attributes of the label elements.  I suppose I could just glean information those return values.  Is there an easier method for this?

Here's an example DOM element from the code.

```
<g class="tick major" transform="translate(73.33333333333333,0)" style="opacity: 1;"><line y2="6" x2="0">
    <line y2="6" x2="0"></line>
    <text y="9" x="0" dy=".71em" style="text-anchor: middle;">banana</text>
</g>
```

My script:

```
var margin = {top: 100, right: 100, bottom: 100, left: 100},
    width = 310 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(["apple", "orange", "banana", "grapefruit"])
    .rangePoints([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)   
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis); 

console.log(svg.selectAll("g.x.axis g.tick.major")
    .attr("transform"))
```

Comment: If `svg.selectAll("g.x.axis g.tick.major").attr("transform")` returns the `g` elements' position it seems simple enough. Does it not work for you somehow? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If you read my post you would have seen that I have already stated that.  I'm looking to dynamically determine if there is overlap of a text label by gathering the x and y coordinates as well as the bounding box sizing so I can determine the placement of the labels with a set of cases.

Comment: I read your post and I know you stated that. I was emitting an opinion.